# Changing color of a view in tableview cell doesn't make change

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm changing background colour of a view in `tableViewCell` but it doesn't change at first load and i need to scroll to see changes. This is my cell class:

```
@IBOutlet weak var status_back: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var status_label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var node_label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var time_label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var name_label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var res_date: UILabel!

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    status_back.layer.cornerRadius = status_back.frame.height/2
}
```

and the code that changes color of status_back in ViewController:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "MealCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ReservationCell
    let reservation = filteredreservations[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
    cell.name_label.text = "نام: "+reservation.client_name
    cell.name_label.font = UIFont(name: "WeblogmaYekan", size: 17)
    cell.time_label.text="زمان: "+reservation.ft_of_time+"-"+reservation.ft_to_time
    cell.time_label.font = UIFont(name: "B Yekan", size: 17)
    cell.res_date.text="تاریخ: \(reservation.date)"
    cell.res_date.font = UIFont(name: "B Yekan", size: 17)
    var status = ""
    if reservation.type {
        cell.node_label.text="ex1 \(reservation.node_title)"
    } else {
        cell.node_label.text="ex2"
    }
    switch reservation.res_status {
    case "CanceledByAdmin":
        cell.status_back.backgroundColor=Utils.UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue: 0xFFFC635D)
        status = "ex"
    case "Canceled":
        cell.status_back.backgroundColor=Utils.UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue: 0xFFEE903D)
        status = "ex"
    case "Deprecated":
        cell.status_back.backgroundColor=Utils.UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue: 0xFF757575)
        status = "ex"
    default:
        cell.status_back.backgroundColor=Utils.UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue: 0xFF3BA757)
        status = "ex"
    }
    cell.status_label.text=status
    cell.status_label.font = UIFont(name: "WeblogmaYekan", size: 17)
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Is your code inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: yes I'm sure @NiravD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer. when cell is created there is no data for `status_back.frame.height` so

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    status_back.layer.cornerRadius = status_back.frame.height/2
}
```

makes `status_back` invisible and the next time it recycled the code works

Answer (score 1):

You must not use break in this situation, as `break` means it'll exit from the switch.

From Swift 3 docs:

> In contrast with switch statements in C and Objective-C, switch
>   statements in Swift do not fall through the bottom of each case and
>   into the next one by default. Instead, the entire switch statement
>   finishes its execution as soon as the first matching switch case is
>   completed, without requiring an explicit break statement. This makes
>   the switch statement safer and easier to use than the one in C and
>   avoids executing more than one switch case by mistake.

The switch control flow **ends right after the certain case is met** in Swift.

```
switch reservation.res_status {
    case "CanceledByAdmin":
        color = Utils.UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue: 0xFFFC635D)
        status = "example4"        
    case "Canceled":
        color = Utils.UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue: 0xFFEE903D)
        status = "example3"
    case "Deprecated":
        color = Utils.UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue: 0xFF757575)
        status = "example2"
    default:
        color = Utils.UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue: 0xFF3BA757)
        status = "example"
    }

    cell.status_label.text=status
    cell.status_back.backgroundColor = color
    cell.status_label.font = UIFont(name: "WeblogmaYekan", size: 17)
    return cell
```

Comment: It ends in the case, that is currently met. You can read all the documentation here https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID139

Comment: thanks for mentioning that but it doesn't fix my problem

Comment: You're welcome. I needed to mention this, as I wasn't sure if this is the issue. I am not over. I'd like to help you either with that issue. Could you post, what outputs this: `print(cell.status_back.backgroundColor)` just before `return cell`?

Comment: it returns right values everything is ok I'm so confused why it's happening

Comment: You say, that you see colour updates after scrolling of the tableView only?

Comment: yes after scrolling down and the up all of cells has right color but before that theyre all white

Comment: Try to comment / hide all code including `func layoutSubviews` and `func awakeFromNib` just for now. The retry. And one more question, is your datasource changing while scrolling?

Comment: nothing changed and no im not changing datasource while scrolling

Comment: Please, post first lines of your cellForRow method, at least instantiation of the cell and how is reservation.res_status retreived.

Comment: Is status_back's corner radius looking good before scrolling?

Comment: i've find out the problem thats radius of status_back. what can i do?

Comment: That's why I asked. So try to simply move `status_back.layer.cornerRadius` line into your `cellForRow` method. Then update your code in question so I can see where you've put it.

Comment: that doesn't solved also i added it to willDisplayCell and again same result

Comment: Well put this right after your switch scope: `cell.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()` or `cell.status_back.layoutIfNeeded()`

Comment: I would to try this again but with previous implementation of your layoutSubviews() and try to get those round corners work.